# Can't flex inner bootstrap card img to same height as outer bootstrap card img

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap cards both with images and one is nested inside the other.

[Stackblits here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6xgvbq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I'd can't seem to flex the inner image to the same height as the outer image.
The inner image has a smaller height unless the page is very large. So it leaves a small space in between the inner card and the outer card.

Shown here.
[image]

I want both images height to be the same so there is no gap on the bottom of the nested card.

Questions -

1. is this an image sizing issue?
2. is this a bootstrap card flexing issue?

Posted code here

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/k9dapp/image/upload/c_scale,w_1920/v1569538702/mainpage/main-one_hn4sle.jpg" class="card-img" alt="yogaband">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; ">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-4">
              <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/k9dapp/image/upload/v1576863803/ll4uksfotqfndhizgt4q.jpg" class="card-img" alt="instructor">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="card-body">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't reproduce the issue. Please edit it so that it shows us the problem and we can see what's happening and the code that causes it, so we are able to help

Comment: I don't think that's possible as the snippet would need bootstrap. The link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6xgvbq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html provides the example in full

Comment: Yes, you can include Bootstrap js library in the snippet. It is better to have it in the question than in external links (see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: added the libs to the snippet.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the nesting of all the cols/rows/cards. You seem to be using cards as general containers rather than what they were meant for. This is messing up the layout. I know we can only see what you have added here, but it really looks like you over-complicating your structure with cards nested in cols nested in other cards. The best solution would be to simplify this structure (or at least use more appropriate classes) and that should help... or at least eliminate some of the complications so that it is more easily fixed.

Comment: In the inspector you can see that It’s the various padding/margin and flex adjustments in each of the divs that is reducing the size of each by a small amount each time, so it you get the nesting right, I thing it should work! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this CSS code to specify images heights.
`.card-img{ height:valueYouWant; }`

Comment: even when I set "card-img" to a min height of say 200px, it's still a little off...